# Autofill input fields

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, autofill

I need following to work. I have an input field *(in my Code `number1`)* and I need to autofill *(**not autocomplete**)* the other input fields *(in my Code `autofill1` + `autofill2`)*.

I'm working with Bootstrap Vue (Bootstrap 4.6 and Vue.js 2).

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="m-2 mt-3">
    <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
      <tbody>
        <h5 class="ml-1">Informations</h5>
        <tr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 m-1">
              <div class="mt-2">number1</div>
              <b-form-input class="form-control" placeholder="1234567" id="number1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
              <div class="mt-2">autofill1</div>
              <b-form-select id="autofill1"> </b-form-select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
              <div class="mt-2">autofill2</div>
              <b-form-select id="autofill2"> </b-form-select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2 ml-1">
              <b-button variant="success" type="submit"><b-icon icon="check-circle-fill"></b-icon> Save Changes</b-button>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

So my goal is to load some data *(first guess was an json file)* into my script and after I write a matching number *(also possible that its a text)* in input field `number1` the other two fields will be autofilled.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

[image: Example picture how it should work]

Structure json data:

```
[
  { "number": 1234567, "autofill1": "Hello", "autofill2": "Goodbye" },
  { "number": 9876543, "autofill1": "Ciao", "autofill2": "Arrivederci" },
  { "number": 1346795, "autofill1": "Hallo", "autofill2": "Tschuess" }
]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplice. Can you give an example of how it should work?

Comment: I've added a picture to show how it should work - hopefully it will help!

Comment: Very good illustration! Can you show how your data in the json-file is structured?

Comment: Added it as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work: [Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8ZGl2PlxuICAgIDxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPVwibnVtYmVyXCIgcGxhY2Vob2xkZXI9XCIxMjM0NTY3XCIgdi1tb2RlbC5udW1iZXI9XCJudW1iZXIxXCIgLz5cbiAgICA8aW5wdXQgdHlwZT1cInRleHRcIiA6dmFsdWU9XCJnZXRBdXRvZmlsbC5hdXRvZmlsbDFcIiAvPlxuICAgIDxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPVwidGV4dFwiIDp2YWx1ZT1cImdldEF1dG9maWxsLmF1dG9maWxsMlwiIC8+XG4gIDwvZGl2PlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblxuPHNjcmlwdD5cbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgICBjb21wdXRlZDoge1xuICAgICAgZ2V0QXV0b2ZpbGwoKXtcbiAgICAgICAgaWYgKCF0aGlzLmRhdGEuZmluZChpdGVtID0+IGl0ZW0ubnVtYmVyID09IHRoaXMubnVtYmVyMSkpIHJldHVybiBbXCJcIixcIlwiXVxuICAgICAgICByZXR1cm4gdGhpcy5kYXRhLmZpbmQoaXRlbSA9PiBpdGVtLm51bWJlciA9PSB0aGlzLm51bWJlcjEpXG4gICAgICB9XG4gICAgfSxcbiAgICBkYXRhKCkge1xuICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHtcbiAgICAgICAgbnVtYmVyMTogdW5kZWZpbmVkLFxuICAgICAgICBkYXRhOiBbXG4gICAgICAgICAgeyBcIm51bWJlclwiOiAxMjM0NTY3LCBcImF1dG9maWxsMVwiOiBcIkhlbGxvXCIsIFwiYXV0b2ZpbGwyXCI6IFwiR29vZGJ5ZVwiIH0sXG4gICAgICAgICAgeyBcIm51bWJlclwiOiA5ODc2NTQzLCBcImF1dG9maWxsMVwiOiBcIkNpYW9cIiwgXCJhdXRvZmlsbDJcIjogXCJBcnJpdmVkZXJjaVwiIH0sXG4gICAgICAgICAgeyBcIm51bWJlclwiOiAxMzQ2Nzk1LCBcImF1dG9maWxsMVwiOiBcIkhhbGxvXCIsIFwiYXV0b2ZpbGwyXCI6IFwiVHNjaHVlc3NcIiB9XG4gICAgICAgIF1cbiAgICAgIH1cbiAgICB9XG59O1xuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7fVxufSJ9)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" placeholder="1234567" v-model.number="number1" />
    <input type="text" :value="getAutofill.autofill1" />
    <input type="text" :value="getAutofill.autofill2" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
      getAutofill(){
        if (!this.data.find(item => item.number == this.number1)) return ["",""]
        return this.data.find(item => item.number == this.number1)
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        number1: undefined,
        data: [
          { "number": 1234567, "autofill1": "Hello", "autofill2": "Goodbye" },
          { "number": 9876543, "autofill1": "Ciao", "autofill2": "Arrivederci" },
          { "number": 1346795, "autofill1": "Hallo", "autofill2": "Tschuess" }
        ]
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some things to the data and than watch for the variable number1 to change...

```html
<template>
    <div class="m-2 mt-3">
      <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
        <tbody>
          <h5 class="ml-1">Informations</h5>
          <tr>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 m-1">
                <div class="mt-2">number1</div>
                <b-form-input class="form-control" placeholder="1234567" id="number1" v-model="number1" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
                <div class="mt-2">autofill1</div>
                <b-form-input class="form-control" id="autofill1" v-model="autofill1" />
              </div>
  
              <div class="col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1">
                <div class="mt-2">autofill2</div>
                <b-form-input class="form-control" id="autofill2" v-model="autofill2" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 mt-2 ml-1">
                <b-button variant="success" type="submit"><b-icon icon="check-circle-fill"></b-icon> Save Changes</b-button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                number1: "",
                autofill1: "",
                autofill2: "",
                jsonDATA: {...}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            findData(key) {
                for(let i=0; i < this.jsonDATA.length; i++){
                    if(this.jsonDATA[i]['number'] === key) return element[i]
                }
                // add somthing when no data in array...
            }
        },
        watch: {
            number1(){
                try {
                    let tmp = this.findData(this.number1)
                    this.autofill1 = tmp['autofill1']
                    this.autofill2 = tmp['autofill2']
                }
            }
        }
    };
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  </style>
```

I havent tested this but this should work... This is not complete, you need to add some behaviour what to do when no data is found...